# How do I write a function that tells me that I am currently looking at the homepage (/index.php)?

Tags: php, function, url

PHP:

```
function is_homepage()
{
}

if(is_homepage())
{
    echo 'You are on the homepage';
}
else
{
    echo 'You are not on the homepage';
}
```

Explanation:

is_homepage, should work in all these cases:

- http://www.domain.com
- https://www.domain.com
- http://domain.com
- http://domain.com/?param=value
- http://domain.com/index.php?param=value

Where it shouldn't work:

- http://subdomain.domain.com
- http://domain.com/otherfile.php?param=value
- etc.

Comment: Why not just have a flag in the PHP page you serve as the homepage?

Comment: Oh, I guess that would work too lol, just thought it would be nicer to do it differently. thanks!

Comment: look into `$_SERVER` variable for all those pages, something will be common. try that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends of course on how your PHP script is laid out. Though the following solution would work in most cases:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/index.php'
```

Comment: what about when you are on a subdomain?

Comment: That won't affect script behavior in any way, since `SCRIPT_NAME` returns current script name.

Answer (score 6):

do a

> print_r($_SERVER);

and you'll see all the data which will help you achieve this.

I would use

> $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

to identify the file\page I'm currently working with.

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_homepage()
{
  return ( ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'www.domain.com' || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'domain.com') && substr( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 9 ) == 'index.php' );

}

if(is_homepage())
{
    echo 'You are on the homepage';
}
else
{
    echo 'You are not on the homepage';
}
```